# How to change UTC hour (HH) to Local Time (HH)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

We are accessing an API that allows us to schedule date/time. We need to check scheduled things so we do NOT double book on the same hour. The API is returning a time as just HH in military. However, it is using UTC HH. So if we schedule something at 1PM it is coming back 18.

I am trying to use Moment.js to change the UTC 18 back to CST (local time). I am failing horribly.

In the example below I am getting 18 from the API and my function below tries to turn to local time (happens to be CST). But the function is just converting or leaving it to 18. Help?

```
function changeTakenHoursFromUTC (taken) {
if(taken) {
  for (var i = 0, len = taken.length; i < len; i++) {

  // construct a moment object with UTC-based input
  var utchour = taken[i].send_hour + ":00:00";
  console.log( "Hour before change " + utchour);
  var h = moment.utc(utchour);

  // convert using the TZDB identifier for US Central time
  h.tz('America/Chicago');
  h.local();
  console.log( "Hour before change " + h._i );
  var s = h.format("HH");
  taken[i].send_hour = s._i;
  console.log( "Taken hour back in taken is " + taken[i].send_hour );

  count += 1;

  if(i == len-1 && count > 0) {
    //
    return;
  }


  } // end for
} // end IF

} // end changeTakenHoursFromUTC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just missing a format string in your `moment.utc(utchour, "HH")`

I created this function to kind of help as an example:

```
function changeTakenHoursFromUTC (taken) {
  // construct a moment object with UTC-based input
  console.log( "Hour before change " + taken);
  var h = moment.utc(taken, "HH");
  console.log(h.format("HH"));
  h.local();
  console.log( "Hour after change " + h.format("HH"));
}

changeTakenHoursFromUTC(18);
```

Comment: If you would like to change the timezone (other than your local timezone), try `moment().utcOffset();`